# EXNetwork error 403 when publishing app to ios with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am currently publishing my app for user testing using Expo, and it works fine when Android users scan the QR code. However when my friend on iOS tries to use the QR code on their Expo Go app(they are logged in), they get the following error: "The Operation couldn't be completed. EXNetwork Error 403". This also happens when I email my friend the link to the project.

Comment: I have the same issue as well.  I think it is recent.  Was there a bug on or forum entry on this one?

Answer (score 15):

It seems like expo changed something recently to conform with the guidelines of Apple.

There are four steps you need to do when you have an app that is currently only being published on your account and others can't access it.

1. Create an organization in expo
2. Add your co-workers to your organization (they need to have an expo account)
3. In your app.json add the slug of your organization under expo and then owner
4. Republish your app

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "NAME",
    "slug": "name",
    "owner": "ORGANIZATION_NAME",
    ...
  }
}
```

Optionally, you could also convert your personal account to an organization.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue, which was resolved by accepting a new policy on the Apple developer website.

The error I got:

```
Apple 403 detected - Access forbidden
```

Answer (score 9):

Encountered the same issue and this worked for me.

1. visit the published URL of your project
2. go to the settings page - members - invite member
3. input the member email
4. member has to accept invitation upon receive

Note! member has to create an account with expo.
steps:

1. in the expo go ios app, navigate to the profile
2. create an account

Comment: This solved my issue.  And super easy.  Provided you are sharing a published app and someone went and got the Expo Go app and quickly made an account and snapped a shot of the QR code.  This would result in the 403 error.  To fix it in that case, it is exactly as you laid out here.  Simply invite that member.  Voila!